# Displaying different sheets at user's demand in a single dashboard -- Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. I am not sure if I can use Tableau to create the following type of interactive dashboard.

Say I have two almost irrelevant data sources. The first one contains daily revenue for some department stores.

```
Store Name  Date      Revenue
-----------------------------
Macy        6/29/16   50,000
Century 21  6/29/16   46,000
Macy        6/28/16   45,000
Century 21  6/28/16   48,000
...
```

I want to use line chart to study the Revenue. So I would use `Date` as the horizontal axis, and `Revenue` as the measure, while using `Store Name` as the color dimension. As a result, it will render several color lines to capture the revenue in terms of date.

For my other data source, it contains similar things. But instead of doing department stores, it contains information about fast food chain restaurants.

```
Restaurant  Date     Revenue
----------------------------
KFC         5/1/16   50,000
McDonald    5/1/16   46,000
KFC         5/2/16   45,000
McDonald    5/2/16   48,000
...
```

I use line chart to study the revenue again.

Now with the dashboard, is there any way I can have a control with menu Fast Food and Department Store, so that if the user clicks Fast Food, the line chart involving Fast Food appears and if the user clicks Department Store, the line chart involving Department Store appears?

So far, I've been able to use this helpful article http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/multiple-sources-one-worksheet to display Fast Food and Department Store at request. But if the user clicks Fast Food, he will get only one line, instead of multiple lines (one for each restaurant).

I hope I have described my problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fairly easily do this using a parameter control and using it as a filter in your sheets.

First, create a parameter control "View Control":

[image]

Next, create a calculated field based on the parameter *for each data source*:

[image]

The calculation should match the data source ('Fast Food' for the fast food source, and so on)

Then place the calculated fields in the filter card and set to `True`. This should hide one of the sheets and show the other. They should never be shown or hidden at the same time.

[image]

Lastly, place both sheets and the parameter control onto a dashboard. It is best to place the two sheets within the same layout container. You should get the following result:

[image]
 *change parameter*:
[image]